# Lightning Component not updating records

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, picklist

I need help getting my muddled-together-lightning-component to update existing records. I do not really know what I'm doing so it's a wonder I've made it this far :) My component lists all child records from a parent and allows user to select all or some and apply a new picklist value to them. But, my save button does not commit the newly chosen options to the existing records. Help!

Here are images of my component:

[image: init]

[image: onchange]

**code (it is a lot)**:

**cmp**

```
    <aura:component access="global" controller="MassUpdateController" 
                implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
    <aura:attribute name="relatedItems" type="MassUpdateController.wrapItemRecord[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedItems" type="MassUpdateController.wrapItemRecord[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="itemDecisionList" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectAll" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedDecision" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="RIM__c" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="RIM_Item__c" type="Object"/>
        <force:recordData aura:id="rRecord"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  targetFields="{!v.RIM__c}"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                          mode="EDIT"/>

    <lightning:card iconName="custom:custom41" 
                    title="{! 'Item List for ' + v.RIM__c.Customer_Name__c}">     

<div class="slds-form slds-p-horizontal_medium" role="list">
<div class="slds-form__row"><div class="slds-form__item" role="listitem">
<div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal slds-is-editing">    
      <lightning:select name="selectItem" label="Apply Decision to Selected:" value="{!v.selectedDecision}" onchange="{!c.setDcn}">
               <option text="None" value="{!v.value}"></option>
               <aura:iteration items="{!v.itemDecisionList}" var="stat">
                     <option text="{!stat}" value="{!stat}"></option>                    
               </aura:iteration>                    
       </lightning:select>
</div></div></div></div>  <!-- BEGIN TABLE JUNK -->

    <table class="slds-table">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps slds-line-height_reset">
                <th class="" style="width:10px">
                    <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="box3" value="{!v.selectAll}" change="{!c.onCheck}"/></th>
                <th class="slds-p-around_xxx-small" scope="col"><div class="" title="Type">Type</div></th> 
                <th class="slds-p-around_xxx-small" scope="col"><div class="" title="Transaction Amount">Amount</div></th>               
                <th class="slds-p-around_xxx-small" scope="col"><div class="" title="Decision">Decision</div></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.relatedItems}" var="itm">
<tr>
    <td><div class="" style="width:10px">
        <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="boxPack" value="{!itm.itemSelected}"/></div>
    </td>

    <td data-label="Type">
    <div class="slds-form-element__control" title="Type">
        <p class="slds-text-body_regular">{!itm.wrapItem.Transaction_Type__c}</p>
    </div></td>

    <td data-label="Transaction Amount">
    <div class="slds-form-element__control" title="Transaction Amount">
           <p><lightning:formattedNumber value="{!itm.wrapItem.Transaction_Amount_Detail__c}" style="currency" currencyCode="USD"/></p>
    </div></td>             

    <td data-label="Decision">
        <ui:inputSelect  class="slds-select spear-select" aura:id="selectItem" value="{!itm.wrapItem.Decision__c}" updateOn="change" >    
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.itemDecisionList}" var="stat">
                <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!stat}" label="{!stat}" value="{!stat==itm.wrapItem.Decision__c}" />            
            </aura:iteration>    
        </ui:inputSelect>

<!-- aura:if isTrue="{!itm.wrapItem.status__c == ''}"><img src="https://spectatorblogs.imgix.net/files/2016/03/ex.jpg"/>
    </aura:if-->&nbsp;
    </td>               
</tr></aura:iteration></tbody><br/> </table>    <!--BEGIN BUTTONS-->

            <div align="center">
                <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="cancel" onclick="{!c.cancel}" />
                <lightning:button variant="brand" label="go" onclick="{!c.changeDcn}" /> 
            </div>

    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

**controller.js**:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAllRelatedItems");  
        action.setParams({
            "visitRecordId" : component.get("v.recordId")});
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {            
            component.set("v.relatedItems", a.getReturnValue());});
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
        helper.getPrepopulatedValues(component, event, helper);},

    onCheck : function(component, event, helper) {
        var selAll = component.get("v.selectAll");
        var newlst =[];    
        var allItems = component.get("v.relatedItems");
        for(var i in allItems){
            var space = allItems[i];                    
            space.itemSelected = selAll;             
            newlst.push(space);}
        component.set("v.selectedItems",newlst);
        component.set("v.relatedItems",newlst);},

    setDcn : function(component, event, helper) {
        var selcDcn = component.get("v.selectedDecision");
        var newlst =[];    
        var allItems = component.get("v.relatedItems");
        for(var i in allItems){
            var space = allItems[i];                    
            if(space.itemSelected === true){
                space.wrapItem.Decision__c = selcDcn;}
            newlst.push(space);}
        component.set("v.relatedItems",newlst);}, 
//please help! ======================================================
    changeDcn : function(component, event, helper) {
         var allItems = component.get("v.relatedItems");
         for(var i in allItems){
           var space = allItems[i];    
           //alert("Decision: " + space.wrapItem.Decision__c);
         }

         var action = component.get("c.saveDcn");
         action.setParams({"dcns":  JSON.stringify(allItems) });
         action.setCallback(this, function(response){
         var state = response.getState();
         if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var stat = component.get("v.itemDecisionList");
            stat.push(response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.itemDecisionList", stat);
         }
       });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);

   },
//===================================================================    
    cancel : function (component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAllRelatedItems");  
        action.setParams({
            "visitRecordId" : component.get("v.recordId")});
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {            
            component.set("v.relatedItems", a.getReturnValue());});
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
        helper.getPrepopulatedValues(component, event, helper);
    },
})
```

**helper**:

```
    ({
        getPrepopulatedValues : function(component, event, helper) {
            var action = component.get("c.getDcnValues");
            action.setCallback(this, function(a) {            
                component.set("v.itemDecisionList", a.getReturnValue());
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        },
    })
```

**controller.apxc:**

```
public class MassUpdateController {
    @auraEnabled
    public static List<wrapItemRecord> getAllRelatedItems(Id visitRecordId){
        List<wrapItemRecord> wrapItemRecordList = new List<wrapItemRecord>();
        for(RIM_Item__c itm : [select Id, Name, RIM__r.Name, Decision__c, Transaction_Amount_Detail__c, 
                               Transaction_Type__c, RIM__r.Customer_Name__c 
                               from RIM_Item__c where RIM__c = :visitRecordId]){
            wrapItemRecordList.add(new wrapItemRecord(itm));
        }
        return wrapItemRecordList;
    }
    @auraEnabled
    public static List<String> getDcnValues(){
        List<String> options = new List<String>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = RIM_Item__c.Decision__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> stat = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry f: stat) {
            options.add(f.getLabel());
        }
        return options;
    }
    //==================================================================
    @auraEnabled
   public static List<RIM_Item__c> saveDcn(String stat){
       List<RIM_Item__c> statList = (List<RIM_Item__c>)JSON.deserialize(stat,List<RIM_Item__c>.class); 
       UPDATE statList;
       RETURN statList;
   }
    //==================================================================

    public class wrapItemRecord{
        @auraEnabled
        public boolean itemSelected{get; set;}

        @auraEnabled
        public RIM_Item__c wrapItem{get; set;}

        @auraEnabled
        public boolean isDecided{get; set;}

        public wrapItemRecord(RIM_Item__c itm){
            itemSelected = false;
            wrapItem = itm;
            if(itm.Decision__c == null){
                isDecided = false;
            }else{
                isDecided = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your Apex `saveDcn` method had `RIM_Item__c ` object  parameter but you send to list of Items

Comment: How do I fix this? I know I need to somehow make it get the output of changeDcn "listy" and push it through..

Comment: I don't know that you're gaining anything with the serialize/deserialize; the main problem is object types. You're passing a list of wrapItemRecord objects and treating them as Rim_Item__c objects. Unwrap your objects before attempting to update them.

Answer (score 0):

As your method passing list and updating and getting a single object that's the problem

Try below code APEX method.

```
//==================================================================
@auraEnabled
public static List<RIM_Item__c> saveDcn(List<RIM_Item__c> dcns){
    UPDATE dcns;
    RETURN dcns;
}
//==================================================================
```

The best way to send the stringify request structure to APEX Call as below.

```
 //please help! ======================================================
    changeDcn : function(component, event, helper) {
         var allItems = component.get("v.relatedItems");
         for(var i in allItems){
           var space = allItems[i];    
           //alert("Decision: " + space.wrapItem.Decision__c);
         }

         var action = component.get("c.saveDcn");
         // instead passing list you can pass stringified value and APEX 
         // method will also change accordingly
         action.setParams({"dcns":  JSON.stringify(allItems) });
         action.setCallback(this, function(response){
         var state = response.getState();
         if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var listy = component.get("v.itemDecisionList");
            listy.push(response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.itemDecisionList", listy);
         }
       });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);

   }, 
  //===================================================================
```

After above modification in cmp controller Below is the APEX Method change

```
 //==================================================================
   @auraEnabled
   public static List<RIM_Item__c> saveDcn(String dcns){
       List<RIM_Item__c> dcnsList = (List<RIM_Item__c>)JSON.deserialize(dcns,List<RIM_Item__c>.class); 
       UPDATE dcnsList;
       RETURN dcnsList;
   }
//==================================================================
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I updated my APEX and it still does not update the fields. How do I get saveDcn in APEX to pull the new values from what changeDcn has listed in the cmpController?

Comment: @Kashona Please review updated answer. Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I've made the adjustments and also changed some of my variables (will update my OP) but still no luck with saving the new values. Could it be something missing in my attributes list? Nothing happens when clicking the save button so something isn't connecting..